# Optimal try..finally placement for CreateProcess .. WaitForSingleObject .. CloseHandle calls

Tags: delphi, createprocess

I want to call CloseHandle after calls to CreateProcess .. WaitForSingleObject and want to enclose the CloseHandle calls in a try..finally block but not sure where to put the different calls w.r.t. try..finally.

Here is my current code:

```
var
  p, f, a: String;
  pi: TProcessInformation;
  si: TStartupInfo;
begin
  Log('Starting backup..');

  if (not FileExists(FMYPROG)) then
  begin
    Log('Error: ' + STR_ERRMSG_1);
    MessageDlg(STR_ERRMSG_1, mtError, [mbOK], 0);
    Exit;
  end;

  // start process up
  FillChar(si, SizeOf(si), 0);
  si.cb := SizeOf(si);
  si.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
  si.wShowWindow := SW_NORMAL;

  f := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(FBAKFILEPATH) + 'output.bak';
  p := '/changesonly "' + f + '"';

  try   // is this the optimal placement for this line? or should it be after CreateProcess? 
    if CreateProcess(PChar(FMYPROG), PChar(p), nil, nil, False,
      CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP + NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, PChar(ExtractFilePath(FMYPROG)), si, pi) then
      WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE)
    else
      RaiseLastOSError;

  finally
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
  end;
```

Suggestions and critique leading to Delphi enlightenment sought. Thank you.

Comment: Write `if not CreateProcess(...) then RaiseLastOSError; try..finally CloseHandles; end;` because you would be closing those handles even when the `CreateProcess` fails.

Comment: The order is always the same: `AcquireResource; try UseResource; finally ReleaseResource; end`. That works for whatever kind of resource you have (in your case, process and thread handles). You simply have to decide what it means to acquire, use, and release them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only call `CloseHandle` if `CreateProcess` succeeds. Therefore it goes like this:

```
if CreateProcess(...) then
  try
    ....
  finally
    // calls to CloseHandle
  end
else
  RaiseLastOSError;
```

Or if you prefer to deal with the error cases up-front:

```
if not CreateProcess(...) then
  RaiseLastOSError;
try
  ....
finally
  // calls to CloseHandle
end
```

This is semantically identical because you know that `RaiseLastOSError` will raise an exception.

Or as I prefer:

```
Win32Check(CreateProcess(...));
try 
  ....
finally
  // calls to CloseHandle
end;
```

The `Win32Check` convenience function simply encapsulates the logic

```
if not Succeeded then
  RaiseLastOSError;
```

Comment: This is different to TLama's comment to the question. Waiting to see his justification.

Comment: No, it's essentially the same. The main point is to skip the `try..finally` block in case when the `CreateProcess` fails. In this post is used `else` for raising the exception. But you will skip that block even if you just raise an exception before entering it (that's what the second snippet does). I've already discarded my answer draft...

Comment: @Steve Yes, it's the same. The point is that the try is only executed if CreateProcess succeeds. I'll add a third option.